# By using laravel 5.1 error that appears in view when trying display image from array by foreach

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to display image from array defined inside controller through foreach loop defined inside view at Laravel 5.1 but i have this error that's appearing because the cache

Error depend on Log in Laravel 5.1

> local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'parse error' in /Users/alaasabra/libapp/storage/framework/views/3bd627f3970d38e63304903ba6823083:9

my controller :

```
   $sections = ['art'=>'art.jpg','mechanic'=>'mechanic.jpg','history'=>'history.jpg',
  'programming'=>'programming.jpg','comic'=>'comic.jpg','civil'=>'civil.jpg'];
    return view('libraryViewsContainer.library')->withDate($date)->withTime($time)->withSections($sections);
```

my view :

```
 <div class="container" style="opacity: 0.9">
    <div class="row">


        @foreach($sections as $k=>$v)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/{{$v}}')}}" />
                <h1><a class="btn btn-primary">{{$k}}</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach

    </div>


</div>
```

the error at display image because the view built by cache at this path :

> Users/alaasabra/libapp/storage/framework/views

displayed like this :

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<div class="container" style="opacity: 0.9">
    <div class="row">


        <?php foreach($sections as $k=>$v): ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<?php echo e(asset('images/{{$v); ?>')}}" />
                <h1><a class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo e($k); ?></a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>


</div>
```

so what is the problem here at line 9 at the last file that built automatically by cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you have nested curly braces.

Change this

```
asset('images/{{$v}}')
```

to this

```
asset('images/'.$v)
```